# Flex 1:1 is not working with Ionic grid. I need to allocate the space 50: 50

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, ionic4

*.scss*

```
.content {
    ion-grid {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .row1 {
        flex: 1 !important;
    }
    .row2 {
        flex: 1 !important;
    }
}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="content">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="row1">
      <ion-col size="12">
          S-Works Venge Disc – SRAM eTAP
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="row2">
      <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12">
            S-Works Venge Disc – SRAM eTAP
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12">
            Availability : Upon Request
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12">
            About
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12">
            We aren't satisfied with second fastest. Hello, why do you think we have our own Win Tunnel and the motto,
            "Aero is Everything?" We live and breathe aero, because we know that aerodynamic optimization is the best
            thing we can do to make you faster. And this philosophy has never been truer than with the new Venge. Being
            eight seconds faster than the ViAS, it’s not only the most aerodynamic bike on the road, but it’s also lost
            460 grams. And now with SRAM RED eTAP, you’re definitively looking at the new shape of speed.
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*result:*

[image]

**Q:** Can you tell me why I can't see `50:50` space allocation with the above design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `flex: 1` property to work, its parent must have the property `display: flex`
By default, the `display: flex` shows its children in a row, that's why we needed to change the direction to column

```
ion-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine. Please provide a little explanation. Here code only answers will be closed or downvoted.

Comment: I added a description, sorry about that. =)

Answer (score -2):

For what I see, the problem seems to be with the shorthand `flex: 1`. Flex shorthands can be a bit tricky in different browsers.

Unfortunately I can't test my solution at this moment, but I would do the following:

```
.row1,
.row2 {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

That way, both items will start at `height: 0` and the flex grow will assign the remaining space to both rows equally

Comment: Don't post answers you haven't tested, or not sure whether they work.

Comment: I'm answering based on the ionic documentation about how ion-grid works and my experience with flexbox, what's the problem?

Comment: On the other hand the accepted solution, doesn't really provide a good solution inside the ionic framework.

ion-grid is already a container with the display flex property, and by adding ion-row elements you're already making them to display on top of each other (same effect with as setting flex-direction: row).

Comment: I didn't mean to say that `flex-direction: row` displays the item on top, I mean that the `ion-row` elements are stacked on top of each other automatically because that's how the `ion-grid` component works. Where it says `(same effect with as setting flex-direction: row)` it should say `flex-direction: column`, my bad there.

I suggested changing the shorthand because the `flex: 1` should already be working and if it's not then it's probably a problem with the browser, here's a working stackblitz with the exact same code OP posted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cdjgbb

Comment: Exactly, it can go both ways, your statement about shorthand being less buggy isn't entirely true.

It's alright, I don't want to get into an endless discussion, I was just puzzled as to why I was getting downvoted against a solution that completely ignored the framework and the actual components OP is using.

Comment: I don't understand, are you just pasting me a flex reference?

Comment: As we spoke about whether to use short or long hand properties, in the official docs. they state _"Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` **shorthand**"_